# Inequality regarding norm vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces

I am not sure how to prove this inequality involving norms.

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and $x,y$ are vectors in $X$ with nonzero norms. Prove the following inequality is true.

$$\|x-y\|\geq \frac{1}{2}\max\{\|x\|,\|y\|\}\left|\left|\frac{x}{\|x\|}-\frac{y}{\|y\|}\right|\right|$$
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We have that
\begin{align}
2\|x-y\|&\ge
\|x-y\|+\big|\|x\|-\|y\|\big|=\|x-y\|+\left\|x-\frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|}x\right\|\ge 
\left\|y-\frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|}x\right\|\\ &=\|y\|\,\left\|\frac{1}{\|y\|}y-\frac{1}{\|x\|}x\right\|,
\end{align}
and similarly, interchanging $x$ and $y$ we obtain
$$
2\|x-y\|\ge\|x\|\,\left\|\frac{1}{\|y\|}y-\frac{1}{\|x\|}x\right\|,
$$
and hence
$$
2\|x-y\|\ge\max\{\|x\|,\|y\|\}\left\|\frac{1}{\|y\|}y-\frac{1}{\|x\|}x\right\|.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your response, this really helps.

Comment: @nerd If this answer left no doubts open, please mark it as "accepted", this can be done by clicking on the grey checkmark next to the question. Also, you should review your other questions to do the same. Accepting answers signals other users that your question is solved and delivers positive feedback to the answerer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a version of Dunkl-Williams Inequality. Check out
"Some remarks on the triangle inequality for norms", by
L.Maligranda, Banach J. Math. Anal. 2 (2008), no. 2, 31–41.